# Getting property 'exporting' undefined when exporting graph on second click

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have issue when I try to export graph to png on second click. First time everything is fine, but on second click I'm receiving this error in console `Cannot read property 'exporting' of undefined`. I'm using React, and my code looks like this

```
const [exportGraph, setExportGraph] = React.useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);

const chartCallback = (chart: Highcharts.Chart) => {
setExportGraph(
  <React.Fragment>
    <ChartAction
      onClick={() => {
        chart.exportChart({}, {});
      }}
      title={t('exportGraphPNG')}
      iconName={EXPORT_ICON}
    />
    <ChartAction
      onClick={() => {
        chart.downloadCSV();
      }}
      title={t('exportGraphCSV')}
      iconName={EXPORT_ICON}
    />
  </React.Fragment>
 );
};

return (
   ...
   <div>{exportGraph}</div>
   ...
);
```

and in chart component I have this defined

```
const handleChartCallback = (chart: Highcharts.Chart) => {
    enableScrollWithMouseWheel(chart);
    chartCallback && chartCallback(chart);
};

return (
   <HighchartsReact
      constructorType={'chart'}
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      callback={handleChartCallback}
   />
)
```

Note that `downloadCSV` works fine on multiple time export, but only until I export png. After that it seem that chart disappear from the dom somehow. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Here https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-colden-cqwfl?file=/src/App.js. Sorry, I couldn't reproduce it better looking, but you can see if you click the PNG button twice, that error will appear.

Comment: Your example looks too complex to find out why the error occurs. Why don't you just a create a reference to the chart and use it to export the chart on the custom button event? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jfwcnc?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved my problem with `useRef`. Please write an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - use `useRef` to create the chart reference to get a `chart` object as a solution for this case.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jfwcnc?file=index.js